# Matlab COM interface to Excel: Get range address without dollar signs

Tags: matlab, excel, com, vba

In VBA, range.address(0,0) or range,address.(false,false) returns an A1 address without dollar signs ('relative referencing' in Excel VBA parlance).

Experimenting with `sht` as a worksheet object, I get the following:

```
K>> sht.Range('B2:C3').Address
    ans = $B$2:$C$3
K>> sht.Range('B2:C3').Address(false,false)
    ans = ''
K>> sht.Range('B2:C3').Address(0,0)
    Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
K>> get( sht.Range('B2:C3'), 'Address' )
    ans = $B$2:$C$3
K>> get( sht.Range('B2:C3'), 'Address(0,0)' )
    Error using Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range/get
K>> invoke( sht.Range('B2:C3') , 'Address', 0, 0 )
    Error using Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range/invoke
K>> invoke( sht.Range('B2:C3') , 'Address', false, false )
    Error using Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range/invoke
K>> methods( sht.Range('B2:C3') ) % Address is not a method
    Methods for class Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range:
    Activate                ClearHyperlinks         <...snip...>
    AddComment              ClearNotes              <...snip...>
    <...snip...>
K>> get( sht.Range('B2:C3') )
            Application: [1x1 Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library._Application]
                Creator: 'xlCreatorCode'
                 Parent: [1x1 Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library._Worksheet]
              AddIndent: 0
                Address: '$B$2:$C$3'
           AddressLocal: '$B$2:$C$3'
                  Areas: [1x1 Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Areas]

                    <...snip...>
```

It seems that in VBA, the `Address` property returns an object with an implied `operator()`, so it can be given arguments (like `false` or 0) to specify local referencing.  From the `get` results, however, the COM interface treats the `Address` property as a simple property with a single literal string value, which is limiting.

To avoid this limitation, I don't suppose there is a way to evaluate a VBA expression (such as what one might type into the Immediate Window of the VBA Editor) from Matlab?  As can be seen above, `invoke` doesn't do it.

I can work around this at the tactical level by writing expressions to remove the dollar signs from the address, but I want a general way to access evalation of VBA from within Matlab.  Also writing tactical formatting functions makes for noisier, more voluminous code.

Comment: You are asking an address from _Excel_, so it replies with an __absolute__ address, hence the `$` sign. This behavior seems normal to me, it is not a "relative" address/offset. Now if it is bothering you, you can use a simple inline helper function: define `cleanAddress=@(s) strrep(str,'$','')` at the top of your code, then you can get your cleaned address directly without the `$` sign. Try `cleanAddress(sht.Range('B2:C3').Address)`

Comment: I realize I can clean up the output and I thank  you for providing that. I was really hoping to find a way to access VBA-compliant syntax and functionality.  For example, the Immediate Window accepts `?ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Address(0,0)` and returns an address using local referencing.  From Matlab, I can get ListObject.DataBodyRange.Address, but it doesn't accept arguments to specify local referencing.  Wondering if such limitations are hard coded into the COM interface, or whether there is a way to have the Excel object evaluate actual VBA expressions without these limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the syntax to [the answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782719/cant-access-range-method-of-range-object-com-limitations)

```
% Open COM interface, create new workbook, access worksheet

excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
excel.Visible=1;
wbks = excel.Workbooks;
wbks.Add
sht = wbks.Item(1).Sheets.Item(1)

% Syntax for range address using absolute reference
sht.Range('A3.B4').Address

% Syntax for range address using relative reference
get( sht.Range('A3.B4'), 'Address', 0, 0 )

% Shut down Excel workbook and COM app object
try
   excel.DisplayAlerts = 0; % Forgo save prompt on Close
end; try
   wbk.Close
end; try
   excel.Quit % Excel process still present
end; try
   delete(excel) % Excel process disappears
end % try
```