# Can't access Range method of Range object; COM limitations?

Tags: matlab, excel, com, vba

In the Excel VBA Editor's Immediate Window, I can do the following:

```
?ActiveSheet.Range("C3:D4").Range("C3:D4").Address
$E$5:$F$6
```

According to some simple tests, this doesn't seem to respond the same in Matlab.  Here is the code to set up the COM interface for the tests:

```
excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
excel.Visible=1;
wbks = excel.Workbooks;
wbks.Add
sht = wbks.Item(1).Sheets.Item(1)

%
%     Run some range tests
%

try
   excel.DisplayAlerts = 0; % Forgo save prompt on Close
end; try
   wbk.Close
end; try
   excel.Quit % Excel process still present
end; try
   delete(excel) % Excel process disappears
end % try
```

Now, with `sht` being a Worksheet object, I get the following error instead:

```
K>> o=sht.Range('C3:D4')
    o = Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range

K>> o.Range('C3:D4').Address

    Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'Range'
    The closest match is: range in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\Single_R2015b\toolbox\stats\stats\range.m
    Did you mean: K>> o.range('C3:D4').Address
```

This is the wrong function, since `range` with an uncapitalized `r` is the internal Matab function.  Hence, I pressed Ctrl-C to break out (otherwise, it complains about the incompatible argument).

To troubleshoot why `Range` is not recognized, check whether is is a method or property.  When accessed via COM, `Range` is a method rather than a property:

```
K>> methods(o)
    Methods for class Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range:
        <...snip...>
        PrintPreview            Table
        Range                   TextToColumns
        RemoveDuplicates        UnMerge
        <...snip...>
```

This further shows that `Range` is not a property (even though it is in VBA):

```
K>> get(o)
         <...snip...>
     QueryTable: 'Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC'
         Resize: [1x1 Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range]
            Row: 3
         <...snip...>
```

Since properties are listed alphabetically, `Range` would show up after QueryTable if it was recognized as a property.  However, it isn't listed in the above results.

As an alternative diagnostic step, I tried accessing `Range` using the dot notation (`o.Range`).  Unfortunately, Matlab seems to got for its own native function `range`, which has nothing to do with an Excel `Range`.

So after all that diagnostic work....

**THE QUESTION**

**For a given `Range` object, how does one access the `Range` method (as recognized by COM) *or* the `Range` property (as it is described in the VBA documentation)?**

**AFTERNOTE**

There seem to be many discrepancies with in accessing Range properties and methods via the COM interface.  In the Immediate Window, one can use the `Offset` property (it is desribed as a property):

```
? ActiveSheet.Range("C3:D4").Offset(2,3).Address
$F$5:$G$6
```

Over COM, not so much, even though `get(o)` shows `Offset` to be a valid property that returns a range:

```
K>> o=sht.Range('C3:D4')
    o = Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range
K>> o=o.Offset(2,2)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I've reached by trial and error, refined with some help with Matlab technical support:

Invoke `get` as a method, then supply the desired property name.  It works for property `Offset`.

```
K>> o = sht.Range('C3:D4')
    o = Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range
K>> o.get('Offset',2,3).Address
    ans = $F$5:$G$6
```

It  works for `Range`, too.

```
K>> o = sht.Range('C3:E5')
    o = Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range
K>> o.get('Range','B2:C3').Address
    ans = $D$4:$E$5
```

The strange thing is that `Range` is a method according to COM (but a property according to the Excel VBA documentation).  Despite being seen as a method when accessed via COM, it needs to be invoked using `get` rather than `invoke`.  The latter yields an error:

```
K>> o.invoke('Range','B2:C3').Address
    Error using Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library.Range/invoke.
    Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'Range'.
    The closest match is: range in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\Single_R2015b\toolbox\stats\stats\range.m
```